# Populating a spinner with specific entries from an array

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am working on an application for Android. For this I am making an Activity in which you select your country and then a spot in that country. I have one spinner that contains a list of all available countries. Now, what I want it to do is get the country that has been selected, then filter a list of spots that I have for the items that start with the country that has been selected. Then it should put the spots for the selected country into a different spinner. Just for clarity, the list of countries is just a list of countries, and the list of spots looks like:

- Country1 - Spot1
- Country1 - Spot2
- Country2 - Spot1
- Country2 - Spot2

And so on.

This is what I thought the code should work like:

- Get selected country from spinner 1.
- Make a new ArrayList containing the spots.
- Make a second empty ArrayList.
- For each entry of the ArrayList containing the spots, check if it starts with the selected country.
- If so, add it to the second ArrayList.
- Once this is all done, make an ArrayAdapter with the second ArrayList.
- Set this ArrayAdapter for spinner 2.

I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String selectedCountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    ArrayList<CharSequence> arraylist = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    arraylist.addAll(R.array.spots_array);
    ArrayList<CharSequence> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    for (i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++) {
        String delimiter = " - ";
        if ((arraylist(i).split(delimiter)).equals(selectedCountry)) {
            arraylist2.add(arraylist(i).string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('-') + 1));
        }

    }
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,  arraylist2<CharSequence>, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    arrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

But it gives several errors:

- At addAll() it says: "The method addAll(int, Collection) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int)"
- At arraylist it says: "The method arraylist(int) is undefined for the type Configuration"
- At string (inside substring) it says: "string cannot be resolved"

I am still relatively new to Android, and am having a lot of trouble getting this working. Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of little mistakes in your code :

- To access an element in an `arraylist` use the `get(position)` method
- When you add your "spot_array", you actually add the id of the resource, not the array itself (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray))

Here is your code updated, it should works or may need some tweaks

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String selectedCountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        List<CharSequence> arraylist = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        arraylist.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.spots_array)));
        List<CharSequence> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        String delimiter = " - ";
        for (int i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++) {
            String country = arraylist.get(i).toString();
            if (country.contains(selectedCountry)) {
                arraylist2.add(country.substring(country.lastIndexOf('-') + 2));
            }

        }
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,  android.R.id.text1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Just a minor correction. 'country.lastIndexOf('-') + 1' should be 'country.lastIndexOf('-') + 2', else it will include the whitespace after '-' too.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you have really helped a ton! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code.

Firstly, the method `addAll` of the ArrayList must take as an argument a `Collection`. You are passing an Android array id `R.array.spots_array`; bear in mind that the Android ids are integers.

The usually method to fetch a string array from Android resources is (inside an activity):

`String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spots_array);`

Second error: you should access the `ArrayList` elements by calling the method `get(position)` , not directly (`arraylist(position)`). Something like `arraylist.get(position)`.

Third error:

`arraylist2.add(arraylist(i).string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('-') + 1));`

should simply be `arraylist2.add(arraylist.get(i));` for adding one list element to another.

More on `ArrayLists` can be found [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html).

Comment: Footers are not allowed here, particularly ones that advertise websites. I've removed the ones from the remainder of your answers, but I'd request that you not add these in the future.